# Is there a way to calculate the dominant color from an asset available in Craft?

Tags: assets, plugins

Given an image uploaded to Craft, I am wondering if there is a plug-in or a native method to detect the dominant color of said image.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's a pretty good plugin that does the trick:
"Image Color" by Keith Mancuso
https://github.com/familiar-studio/Craft-Image-Color

Comment: The plugin has a few issues, most notably that it doesn't work with S3 assets right out the box. It's an easy to fix issue, that will probably go away in future versions.